# What happened to Ravana's body after his death?

Tags: ramayana, death, ravana, samskara

As per this [YT Video](https://youtu.be/1mMp5ABkEss), it is said Ravana's body antim samskara never happened and some tribe people tried to cure him but couldn't make any success. Is this really true? If not what really happened with the body after his death?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### False.

The antim samskara (funeral rites) of Ravana's body was performed by Vibishana.

---

After the death of Ravana in war with Rama. Rama asks Vibishana to perform funeral rites to Ravana's body

> In the meanwhile, Rama spoke to Vibhishana as follows: **"Let the
>   obsequies of your brother be performed** and let these crews of women be
>   consoled."
>
> [[93, Sarga 111, Yuddha Kanda, Valmiki Ramayana]](https://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/yuddha/sarga111/yuddha_111_frame.htm)

Vibishana initially says to Rama that he is not obliged to perform the obsequies to Ravana's body due to badness of Ravana. The following are the words of Vibishana

> **I am not obliged to perform the obsequies to him**, who had abandoned
>   the vow of virtue, who was cruel, who killed human beings, who was a
>   cheater and who had longed for others' wives. This Ravana, who was
>   interested in wishing evil to all, though venerable as a respectable
>   elder, is not fit for honour. He is my enemy, in the guise of a
>   brother. If I do not perform obsequies, O Rama, the human beings on
>   earth will speak about me as ruthless. But, on hearing about his bad
>   qualities all of them will speak of it as a good act.
>
> [[95-97, Sarga 111, Yuddha Kanda, Valmiki Ramayana]](https://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/yuddha/sarga111/yuddha_111_frame.htm)

Rama then says to Vibishana to perform funeral rites to Ravana's dead body by saying that hostilities ends with death. The following are the words by Rama to Vibishana

> Hostilities end with death. Our purpose has been accomplished. **Let his
>   funeral rites be performed**. He is even as good mine also, as yours.
>   According to rule, Ravana is eligible to get the last rites on his
>   dead body from you, by usage. You will also become fit for glory.
>
> [[102-103, Sarga 111, Yuddha Kanda, Valmiki Ramayana]](https://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/yuddha/sarga111/yuddha_111_frame.htm)

On hearing the words of Rama, Vibishana performs the funeral rites to Ravana's body according to scriptures.The following are the funeral rites performed on Ravana's body

> Entering the City of Lanka, that Vibhishana, the lord of demons,
>   quickly concluded the Agnihotra (the act of pouring oblations into the
>   sacred fire) carried on by Ravana.  Vibhishana actually caused to be brought together, carts, excellent varieties of firewood, the three sacred fires and the priests required
>   to officiate at the obsequies, logs of sandalwood, various types of
>   firewood, pieces of fragrant aloe-wood, odorous perfumes, as well as
>   gems, pearls and corals. Surrounded with demons, he came back for a while and thereupon,
>   Vibhishana along with malyavan (the father of his own mother)
>   initiated the obsequies.
>    Vibhishana actually caused to be brought together, carts, excellent
>   varieties of firewood, the three sacred fires and the priests required
>   to officiate at the obsequies, logs of sandalwood, various types of
>   firewood, pieces of fragrant aloe-wood, odorous perfumes, as well as
>   gems, pearls and corals.
>   Surrounded with demons, he came back for a while and thereupon,
>   Vibhishana along with malyavan (the father of his own mother)
>   initiated the obsequies.
>   Placing Ravana, the lord of demons, who was covered with linen,
>   accompanied by blasts of various musical instruments as well as
>   panegyrists singing his the Brahmanas (forming part of the demon's
>   race, which was apparently divided into four classes, like human
>   beings) stood around him with their faces filled in tears. Lifting up
>   that palanquin, which had been decorated with colorful flags and
>   flowers and taking up blocks of wood, all the demons for their part,
>   with Vibhishana in front, proceeded with their face turned towards the
>   south.
>   Those sacrificial fires were ignited and re-animated, as they were, by
>   Adhvaryu priests, the performers of the sacrificial act, at that time.
>   Those sacrificial fires were contained in earthen pots and went in
>   front of Ravana's body.
>   All those women of the gynaecium, while weeping, followed at his heels
>   with quick paces, stumbling, as they were, on all sides.
>   Keeping the body of Ravana on a consecrated spot, Vibhishana and
>   others, who were very much afflicted with grief, piled up a sacred
>   pyre, with logs of sandalwood, moistened with perfumes called Padmaka
>   and Koshira and covered with the skin of black antelopes, turned about
>   to perform the obsequies in accordance with Vedic rites in honour of
>   the king.
>   **They performed the ancestral oblations to Ravana in a superb way**. They
>   constructed an altar in the south-east the funeral pile) and placed
>   the sacred fire in its proper place.
>   They poured a ladle-full of ghee mixed with curds on his shoulders,
>   placed a cart at his feet and then a wooden mortar at his thighs.
>   Having set at their proper place, all the wooden vessels (used in
>   Agnihotra), the lower piece of wood used for kindling fire at a
>   sacrifice and the upper piece of wood (which is rotated at great speed
>   on to lower one, to produce fire by friction), the wooden pestle and
>   other things used in the sacrifice, they circled around the funeral
>   pyre.
>   According to ordinance laid down by eminent sages and according to the
>   rules viewed in Vedas, having sacrificed a goat fit for sacrifice at
>   that spot, the demons dampened with ghee on Ravana the King of demons.
>   Having decorated the body of Ravana with perfumes, garlands and
>   various kinds of clothes; those demons accompanied by Vibhishana,
>   distressed as they were in their minds, poured parched grains of rice,
>   with their faces bathed in tears.
>   **That Vibhishana set fire to Ravana, according to the rules in the
>   scriptures**. Washing himself and offering in his wet clothes, according
>   to scriptural ordinance, sesame seeds mixed with water, as well as
>   blades of Kusha grass and offering obeisance to Ravana by bowing his
>   head, Vibhishana entreated those women to return, consoling them again
>   and again. Then, all of the returned to the City.
>
> [[105-125, Sarga 111, Yuddha Kanda, Valmiki Ramayana]](https://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/yuddha/sarga111/yuddha_111_frame.htm)

Thus it is **false** that  *Ravana's body antim samskara never happened and some tribe people tried to cure him but couldn't make any success*.